# Xml serialization and empty file

Tags: c#, windows-services, xml-serialization

I stomped on some very weird bug which is very hard to reproduce I literally cant reproduce it. We have a window service installed on around 300+ PCs. From time to time config file(xml) that is used by this service become clear (on some of them). Totally clear no xml tags, nothing, 0kb. I have no clue what can cause such problem. No exception is logged in our logs. Even after this config becoming clear it's still running however it's not communicating with our web service. This is the class that is used for xml serialization and deserialization. I can’t find what can be possibly causing such behavior. Of course problem might not be in this particular class. Any suggestions?? Maybe some hints what can cause a file to become clear. When any operation on this file is by using this class.

Sorry for my bad English.

```
[XmlRootAttribute("xmlconfig", Namespace = "DSD_Config", IsNullable = false)]
public class xmlconfig
{
    [XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable = false)]
    public string ProgramApteczny { get; set; }
    public string Server { get; set; }
    public string Database { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string DSDUser { get; set; }
    public string DSDPassword { get; set; }
    public string DSDServerAdres { get; set; }

    //public static string cofFile = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\DSD_Agent\\config.xml";
    public static string cofFile = Application.StartupPath + "\\config.xml";

    public xmlconfig()
    {
    }

    public xmlconfig(string sProgramApteczny, string sServer, string sDatabase, string sUser, string sPassword, string sDSDUser, string sDSDPassword, string sDSDServerAdres)
    {
        ProgramApteczny = sProgramApteczny;
        Server = sServer;
        Database = sDatabase;
        User = sUser;
        Password = sPassword;
        DSDUser = sDSDUser;
        DSDPassword = sDSDPassword;
        DSDServerAdres = sDSDServerAdres;
    }

    public static void readXMLConfig(out xmlconfig configFile)
    {
        XmlSerializer oSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(xmlconfig));
        configFile = new xmlconfig(); 

        try
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(cofFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                 configFile = (xmlconfig)oSerializer.Deserialize(fs);

                 try
                 {
                     configFile.Password = Encryption.DecryptString(configFile.Password);
                 }
                 catch (Exception)
                 {
                     configFile.Password = configFile.Password;
                 }

                 try
                 {
                     configFile.DSDPassword = Encryption.DecryptString(configFile.DSDPassword);
                 }
                 catch (Exception)
                 {
                     configFile.DSDPassword = configFile.DSDPassword;
                 }
            }
        }
        catch 
        {
            configFile = null;
        }
    }

    public static void writeXMLConfig(string sProgramApteczny, string sServer, string sDatabase, string sUser, string sPassword, string sDSDUser, string sDSDPassword)
    {
        xmlconfig oxmlconfig = new xmlconfig();
        readXMLConfig(out oxmlconfig);

        sPassword = Encryption.EncryptString(sPassword);
        sDSDPassword = Encryption.EncryptString(sDSDPassword);

        if (oxmlconfig == null)
        {
            oxmlconfig = new xmlconfig(sProgramApteczny, sServer, sDatabase, sUser, sPassword, sDSDUser, sDSDPassword, "");
        }
        else
        {
            oxmlconfig.ProgramApteczny = sProgramApteczny;
            oxmlconfig.Server = sServer;
            oxmlconfig.Database = sDatabase;
            oxmlconfig.User = sUser;
            oxmlconfig.Password = sPassword;
            oxmlconfig.DSDUser = sDSDUser;
            oxmlconfig.DSDPassword = sDSDPassword;
        }

        XmlSerializer oSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(xmlconfig));
        TextWriter oStreamWriter = null;
        try
        {
            oStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(cofFile, false);
            oSerializer.Serialize(oStreamWriter, oxmlconfig);
        }
        catch (Exception oException)
        {
            WriteToLog(DateTime.Now, "Aplikacja wygenerowała następujący wyjątek: " + oException.Message);
            // Console.WriteLine("Aplikacja wygenerowała następujący wyjątek: " + oException.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (null != oStreamWriter)
            {
                oStreamWriter.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void writeXMLDSDConfig(string sDSDServerAdres)
    {
        xmlconfig oxmlconfig = new xmlconfig();
        readXMLConfig(out oxmlconfig);

        if (oxmlconfig == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Aplikacja wygenerowała następujący wyjątek: Musisz zdefiniować wszystkie parametry");
        }
        else
        {
            oxmlconfig.DSDPassword = Encryption.EncryptString(oxmlconfig.DSDPassword);
            oxmlconfig.Password = Encryption.EncryptString(oxmlconfig.Password);
            oxmlconfig.DSDServerAdres = sDSDServerAdres;
        }

        XmlSerializer oSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(xmlconfig));
        TextWriter oStreamWriter = null;
        try
        {
            oStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(cofFile, false);
            oSerializer.Serialize(oStreamWriter, oxmlconfig);
        }
        catch (Exception oException)
        {
            throw new Exception("Aplikacja wygenerowała następujący wyjątek: " + oException.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (null != oStreamWriter)
            {
                oStreamWriter.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How big is this file? If it isn't huge, and you are having problems, I wonder if you should serialize it to memory first (`MemoryStream`), and then **if successful** write the the contents to disk...

Comment: Maybe you could run some kind of tool which captures all file accesses to see if you can narrow it down to what is changing it and when? You can use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to do this. Other than that I would be suspicious about an exception causing the file content writing to be skipped somewhere.

Comment: No it's  small 1-2KB tops.

Answer (score 0):

What I guess, the xml file is accessed by multiple computers/windows services; if so?

Looks no locking mechanism is being used while reading and writing the file. a possible work around would be using a single instance class that only allows one thread to read/write file at one time.

```
bool isInProgress=false

Public void Read()    
{    
    if(isInProgress==false)    
    {    
        isInProgress=true;  

        try    
        {    
            //Do reading or writing
        }    
        finally
        {
            isInProgress=false;
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: I think i didnt make it clear. We have this service installed in 300+ diferent places and each one of them have own config. However in application we have timer that ask web service for some information in fixed intervals. Maybe there is a problem. I will try locking idea.